# Welcome file list not being picked in Websphere

Tags: websphere, welcome-file

I have a peculiar problem. We have welcome file list in web.xml. When we deploy the war on tomcat / JBoss and hit our URL without the html file in welcome file list, the app is redirected properly. However the same redirection is not happening in Websphere. Do we have to do anything else to make it work on Websphere?

Snippet of web.xml -

```
<filter>
<filter-name>AppFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.proj.filters.AppFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>AppFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

What we expect is when we hit application url, it should be appeded with welcome file and my filter should be invoked. This is working on JBoss, but not on Websphere.

Comment: in your index.html loading? and where is your index.html?

Comment: index.html is not loaded. It is in the Application root.

Comment: try this : in Servers -> Server -> Web Container Settings -> Web Container -> Custom Properties, set com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokefilterscompatibility=true

Comment: if it doesnt't work, try this :  

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.mapFiltersToAsterisk=true
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.removetrailingservletpathslash=true
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFiltersCompatibility=true

Comment: Hi, sorry should have mentioned earlier, we have done the above settings as well.

Comment: ok.. try adding <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> in the <filter-mapping>

Comment: or if you just want a servlet to be called , you can follow this link http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/HowToUseAServletAsYourMainWebPage

Comment: Ok so the problem was welome file was picked up, but the url was not geting changed. I made changes to display full url in browser and the filter is now invoked.

Comment: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokefilterscompatibility=true is not needed/used as of WebSphere v8.